# Converting a csv to dict with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a csv that when loaded looks like this.

```
chicken, meat
veal, meat
rice, carbs
potato, carbs
carrot, veggies
mushroom, veggies
apples, fruits
```

I want to create a dictionary from it, so I'm using the code:

```
food = pd.read_csv('foods.csv',  header=None, index_col=1, squeeze=False).to_dict()
```

When i print the dictionary only one item is showing for each key. Instead I would like all to show like this.

```
{'carbs':['potato','rice'],
'meat':['chicken','veal'],
'veggies':['mushroom','carrot'],
'fruits':['apples']}
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use pandas here? Using it merely to convert a csv to a dict is very inefficient

Comment: `pd.read_csv('foods.csv',  header=None).groupby([1])[0].agg(list).to_dict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip Pandas and deal with the file directly. Since you actually have a two character delimiter `', '` it is easier to skip csv too:

```
di={}
with open('/tmp/fruit.csv') as f:
    for x,y in (line.rstrip().split(', ') for line in f):
        di.setdefault(y, []).append(x)

>>> di
{'meat': ['chicken', 'veal'], 'carbs': ['rice', 'potato'], 'veggies': ['carrot', 'mushroom'], 'fruits': ['apples']}
```

Or use pandas:

```
df=pd.read_csv('/tmp/fruit.csv',  header=None, sep=', ', engine='python').groupby([1])[0].agg(list).to_dict()

>>> df
{'carbs': ['rice', 'potato'], 'fruits': ['apples'], 'meat': ['chicken', 'veal'], 'veggies': ['carrot', 'mushroom']}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need Pandas, this can be done easily enough using Python's CSV reader.

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict


category_food_map = defaultdict(list)

with open('foods.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        food, category = row
        category = category.strip()

        category_food_map[category].append(food)


for category, food in category_food_map.items():
    print(f'{category}: {food}')
```

and I get:

```
meat: ['chicken', 'veal']
carbs: ['rice', 'potato']
veggies: ['carrot', 'mushroom']
fruits: ['apples']
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pure python [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library which provides lots of data processing primitives and fosters functional approach:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# store converter for future reuse
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item(1))
    .aggregate(
        {
            # use c.ReduceFuncs.ArrayDistinct(c.item(0)) if you need only
            # unique values in lists
            c.item(1): c.ReduceFuncs.Array(c.item(0)),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter()
)

# stream reading and processing if needed
rows = Table.from_csv(
    "tmp2.csv", dialect=Table.csv_dialect(skipinitialspace=True)
).into_iter_rows(list)
result = converter(rows)

assert result == [
    {'meat': ['chicken', 'veal']},
    {'carbs': ['rice', 'potato']},
    {'veggies': ['carrot', 'mushroom']},
    {'fruits': ['apples']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.groupby(" meat").agg(list).chicken.to_dict()
```

out：

```
{' carbs': ['rice', 'potato'],
 ' fruits': ['apples'],
 ' meat': ['veal'],
 ' veggies': ['carrot', 'mushroom']}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.